# TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method python

Tags: python, selenium, slice

Why does:

```
k = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("#mw-content-text > div > p:nth-child(3) > b:nth-child(1)")[0:6]
```

Work

But

number 6 (aka titles.text) of wiki gives

```
k = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("#mw-content-text > div > p:nth-child(3) > b:nth-child(1)")[0:titles.text]
```

Error:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

How do I get around this? Why is it doing this

the code

```
cd = webdriver.chrome()
cd.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6')
titles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("#mw-content-text > div > p:nth-child(3) > b:nth-child(1)")
for title in titles:
    print(title.text)
```

Changes it to int(titles.text) gives print of all elements

Comment: What do you expect the faulty line should do?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I expect it to scrape 6 elements as the working example does

Comment: `titles.text` is a string. Does it contain `'6'`? If so, use `int(titles.text)`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 of 6'

Comment: So `titles.text` does not contain `'6'`. Why do you think that the content of `titles.text` should somehow mean `6`?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Well it is a 6 in text printed of webpage.  But when  I put it into [0:titles.text], python ignores it completely

Comment: The complete content of `titles.text` is obviously `'1 of 6'`. This is a string containing 2 numbers. You have to write code to extract the right one. Read about `str.split()` or about the `re` module in the Python docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments, it looks like that the value of `titles.text` is, first of all, a string (and hence cannot be used as a slice index) and is equal to `1 of 6` which means that you would not be able to directly pass it to `int()` for conversion.

If you want to extract that `6` from the string, you first can split the string by `of` and then get the last element. Then, you would need to convert it to an integer:

```
max_pages = int(titles.text.split(" of ")[-1])

k = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("#mw-content-text > div > p:nth-child(3) > b:nth-child(1)")[:max_pages]
```